# how to implement quick sort?

Tags: c++

I am using the Splash kit library.

```
#include "splashkit.h"

#define NUM_VALS 100
//drawing 100 random values in chart
void draw_values(const int values[], int size) 
{
    int x = 0;
    int y;
    int rect_height;
    int rect_width = screen_width() / size;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        rect_height = values[i];
        y = screen_height() - rect_height;

        fill_rectangle(COLOR_RED, x, y, rect_width, rect_height);
        draw_rectangle(COLOR_WHITE, x, y, rect_width, rect_height);

        x += rect_width;
    }
}
//swap procedure
void swap (int &value1, int &value2)
{
    int temp = value1;
    value1 = value2;
    value2 = temp;
}
//draw array values window
void draw_sort(int values[], int size)
{
    clear_screen(COLOR_WHITE);
    draw_values(values, size);
    refresh_screen(60);
}
//bubble sort code using above procedures
void bubble_sort (int values[], int size)
{
    for (int j =0; j < size; j++)
    {
        for (int i =0; i < size - 1; i++ )
        {
            if (values[i] > values[i + 1])
            {
                swap(values[i], values[i + 1]);
                draw_sort(values, size);
            }
        }
    }
}
// i think something wrong in this function only
void quick_sort(int values[], int size) {
      int i = values[size + 1] , j = values[size - 1] ;
      int tmp;
      int pivot = values[(i + j) / 2];

      /* partition */
      while (i <= j) {
            while (values[i] < pivot)
                  i++;
            while (values[j] > pivot)
                  j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                  tmp = values[i];
                  values[i] = values[j];
                  values[j] = tmp;
                  i++;
                  j--;
            }
      };

      /* recursion */
      if (i < j)
            quick_sort(values, i);
      if (i < j)
            quick_sort(values, j);
}
// randomising array values to sort
void random_fill_array(int values[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        values[i] = rnd(screen_height()) + 1;
    }
}
//to test each sort
void handle_input(int values[], int size)
{
    if (key_typed(R_KEY))
    {
        random_fill_array(values, size);
    }
    else if (key_typed(S_KEY))
    {
        bubble_sort(values, size);
    }
    else if (key_typed(D_KEY))
    {
        quick_sort(values, size);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int values[NUM_VALS];

    open_window("Sort Visualiser", 800, 600);

    random_fill_array(values, NUM_VALS);

    while ( not quit_requested() )
    {
        process_events();
        handle_input(values, NUM_VALS);

        draw_sort(values, NUM_VALS);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I overcame earlier issues but now i got a new problem. It's not my assignment. I'm just getting to know all the sorts; please tell me where I went wrong.

I tried fixing it when I run now if I press "S" my bubble > sort is > getting sort but when I press "D" Application getting crashed can anyone spot me where am I going wrong?

Comment: `Partition` has two arguments `Partition(int values[], int size)`, you're calling it with 3: `Partition(values, low, high)`. Isn't that what "too many arguments" means?

Comment: And inside the `Partition` function you use the uninitialized variables `low` and `high`, and you never use the argument `size`. Maybe it should take those as parameters, not declare them as local variables?

Comment: `swap(&values[high], &values[pvt]);` would swap pointers to the values, instead of the values. And why not use `std::swap`? Also, I believe the random call can make the `pindex` have extreme values, making the recursive call with `pindex-1` or `pindex+1` out-of-range.

Comment: `swap` takes references, not pointers. You managed to get the call right in the bubble sort.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: thanks for the advices i edited some this is my first semester in bachelors degree im still learning im not professional programmer yet please give me some hints overcome it

Answer (score 1):

This looks really suspicious:

```
/* recursion */
 if (i < j)
      quick_sort(values, i);
 if (i < j)
      quick_sort(values, j);
```

Conditions are exactly the same in both cases